# Importing a big Excel sheet with xlsx

Tags: r, excel, xlsx

I am using the functions **read.xlsx** and **read.xlsx2** from the package **xlsx** to import a couple of Excel sheets from a 6.3 Mo Excel file. It used to work but now I get an error:

```
library(xlsx)
data <- read.xlsx2(file = "file.xlsx", sheetName = "sheet1", encoding = "UTF-8", stringsAsFactors = FALSE, header = TRUE)
Error in .jcall("RJavaTools", "Ljava/lang/Object;", "invokeMethod", cl,  : 
  java.lang.OutOfMemoryError: Java heap space
```

I tried to modify the **java.parameters** before loading **rJava** but it did not help:

```
options(java.parameters = "-Xmx2048m")
library(xlsx)
```

I need to use the package **xlsx** (and not **XLConnect** or **openxlsx**) because I need the **encoding** argument of the above-mentioned functions.

Also I do not want to manually (or using another programming language) convert my Excel sheets to .csv files because I am regularly updating these Excel sheets and I do not want to have to convert them all the time.

Does anyone have an idea how to solve that?

I am using R version 3.3.2 and RStudio version 0.99.903 on macOS Sierra 10.12.1.

Comment: What about using a larger value, say 4 GB? `options(java.parameters = "-Xmx4g")`. Alternatively, have you tried `read_excel` from the `readxl` package? I'm not sure if it will work with your encoding issues, but you could give it a try. `readxl` doesn't require java.